# Restore Redis dump to a different database

Tags: redis

How can I dump a redis that's running on database 0 and restore it in my local machine on a different database (8) ?

I already secure copied the dump file:

```
scp hostname@/var/lib/redis/dump.rdb .
```

But if I change my local redis dump.rdb with this one, I'll get the data on database 0. How can I restore it to a specific database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a script in Ruby to dump and restore the keys I wanted. (Please note that this approach is slow, takes around 1 min for 200 keys) .

- Get the keys to dump / restore

`ssh hostname redis-cli --scan --pattern 'awesome_filter_pattern*'`

- Open an ssh connection to the production server
- Dump the remote key

`dump = ssh.exec!("redis-cli dump #{key}").chomp`

- Restore it on localhost

`$redis.connection.restore(key, 0, dump)`

Answer (score 3):

Firstly note that the use of numbered/shared Redis databases is inadvisable. You really should consider using dedicated Redis servers with a single DB (0) on them (more info at: https://redislabs.com/blog/benchmark-shared-vs-dedicated-redis-instances)

Redis does not offer a straightforward way to do this, but there are two basic ways one could go about it:

1. Pre-processing: modify the dump.rdb file to load into your database of choosing. You could build a tool for that or perhaps use one of the existing ones. Jan-Erik has done an outstanding job of documenting the RDB v7 format at http://rdb.fnordig.de/file_format.html so all you need to do is basically change the `Database Selector` byte.
2. Post-restore: use the [`MOVE`](http://redis.io/commands/move) command on the output of [`SCAN`](http://redis.io/commands/scan)ing your restored database - should be easily scriptable.

Comment: Actually I'm only using a shared server on my development machine so I can have data from different production instances. Your second option (the restore) would delete all my development databases, so I'm gonna try the pre-processing option. Thanks

Comment: Since Redis is very lightweight, you can simply run multiple Redis instances (using different ports) on your development machine.