# Fastest way to copy Redis db with Node.js

Tags: node.js, redis

We have a redis db that's misbehaving in terms of using standard CLI tools to dump/copy the data. So we are just going to copy it programmatically.
I have this code right now:

```
import * as Redis from 'ioredis';
import * as async from 'async';

export type EVCb<T = any, E = any> = (err?: E, val?: T) => void;
export type Task<T> = (cb: EVCb<T>) => void;


const redis = new Redis({
  port: 6379,
  db: 0
});

const redis2 = new Redis({
  port: 6379,
  db: 1
});


export const run = (cb: EVCb<void>) => {

  const q = async.queue<Task<any>>((task, cb) => task(cb), 3);

  let scanCount: number = -5000;

  const getNext = () : number => {
    return scanCount = scanCount + 5000;
  };

  const add = () => {

    const scanCount = getNext();

    q.push(async cb => {

      try {
        const [x, v] = await redis.scan(scanCount);

        if(v.length < 1){
          return cb(null);
        }

        add();

        const d: Array<any> = await redis.mget(...v);

        let i = 0;

        const z = v.reduce((a,b) => (a.set(b, d[i++]), a), new Map());

        await redis2.mset(z);

      } catch (e) {
        return cb(e);
      }

      cb(null);

    }, err => {

      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }

    });

  };


  add();
  add();
  add();

  q.drain(cb);

};
```

it's not the best code, but it should work. Does anyone know if there is a faster way to copy all the keys/values from one db to another?  As an aside, does anyone know why the async queue never drains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to copy on the same Redis instance (from database `0` to `1`) - you might want to check [answer to "Restore Redis dump to a different database"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31883742/613118) and perhaps copy RDB/AOF content twice and then tweak it (one copy for each DB number).